# Change Direction of Scroll in Horizontal Scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi I am creating Scroll effect Like this website https://durimel.io/nel and For this I am using a GitHub repo https://github.com/corentinfardeau/horizontal-scroll#container-node-dom-null, I have two Concerns the Primary Concern is that How can I change the direction of scroll in horizontal Scrolling {Means Like **when I am moving my scroll wheel of mouse Forward the Text is going From left to right "But How can I change it from Right to Left"**} Pretty much same like in the reference website when we are scrolling one line is going from right left and two vice versa. Today I spent a lot of time surfing through the internet for find the answer **How we can change the direction of Scroll in Horizontal Scrolling?**

The second Concern is the **How can I make the horizontal scrolling infinite?** Means Like When I am scrolling to the end (till item 12 {you will get that when you will see the codepen}) the scrolling Stops But I do not want scrolling to be stopped instead the item 1 have to come again Pretty much same like the reference website I have given in the first line .

Here is the Code Pen `<!-- https://codepen.io/shayan-kanwal/pen/RwZdvmw -->` 
Thanks For help Advance